# Excel compare two columns and list a third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet which has 3 Columns:

```
A  B   C    D
1  A   1
2  B   3
3  C   4
       6
5  D

7  E
```

I want to check column C for values present in column A and list corresponding values of column B  in Column D:

```
Result:

A  B   C    D
1  A   1    A
2  B   3    C
3  C   4
       6
5  D

7  E
```

I have achieved the first part by doing:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),"True","False")
```

This lists `True` besides the value on Column C values in Column A. I am unsure how to do the other part using a formula. Can I get some suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your current formula to use a `VLOOKUP` as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,0),"")
```

The above will give you the corresponding B value for the matching A number, and give you blank if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

Could not check, but `VLOOKUP` is what you want.
`VLOOKUP(C2;A$2:A$10;4)`
I cannot test exactly. Put in de first row und pull in the right lower corner.
The $ tells it, not to change the row when copying to the other rows.